# Enable Tag warning

Tags: discussion, status-declined

We carry some tags around which are frequently misused, despite their usage guidance messages, e.g. [raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation):

> The Raspberry Pi Foundation created the Raspberry Pi.  Please, DO NOT use this tag just because it is something to do with one of their products, the entire site is about that anyway!

Luckily there is a feature to help the users guide to a proper use tags:  [tag warnings](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6617/should-we-enable-tag-specific-popups) (follow link for the look&feel). The warning will pop up when entered into the question and that would be the final moment to give some advice how to or how not to use it. See [this example](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8523/virtualbox-tag-warning).

**So this is not so much a question about whether to implement it or not, but a collection of proplematic tags and appropriate tag warnings to go with them.**

We'll collect them for a while and trigger a community manager to set them up when ready. Feel free to add new tags (one tag per answer), make your answer community wiki to help easy editing, and please propose changes to the tag warning messages.

---

Deadline for contribution to that matter: **March, 31st**

Please note that we, the users and admins of Raspberrypi.Stackexchange cannot make the necessary changes. We need to have a community manager do it. It would be advisable to hand in all relevant tag/warning combinations together. So please do not hesitate to make suggestions now.

Comment: Any further input on that? Please!?

Comment: Before implementing a block I wonder if this tag is even needed? Of the 7 questions tagged with it 7 are closed or are on-hold, the other 3 are questionable IMO if they really are on-topic. So if the tag isn't useful, isn't attracting good questions do you even need it?

Comment: @bluefeet: it is used correctly on occasion, but there are a few of us that will edit a question to remove it.

Comment: Discussion here: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/780/what-should-we-do-to-raspberry-pi-foundation

Answer (score 7):

[raspberry-pi-foundation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi-foundation)

> This tag is to be used for questions relating to the Raspberry Pi Foundation, the official Raspberry Pi website, or the origins of the Raspberry Pi only. Please, DO NOT use this tag just because your question has something to do with one of their products; that's the entire point of this site!

Comment: Note that this does gets ~ 20 mistagged questions per month

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [what bluefeet noted in the comments](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/730/enable-tag-warning#comment1427_730), I'm gonna suggest that any tag that *starts* with "raspberry-pi" is gonna be pretty much doomed to misuse here.

A warning is... Probably the wrong tool for the job here. Consider just renaming it to "foundation" or some such, and I'll bet you avoid most of the issues you've been seeing.

Comment: The thing is that "Raspberry Pi Foundation" is a proper name, the name of said foundation. I have the feeling that *foundation* is of little help either. Unfortunately you might be right that this tag is really doomed. We'll discuss the isse, as I mentioned to bluefeet and get back to you.

Comment: If you just use "Foundation" we'll end up with Isaac Asimov crossover questions. ;)  That's okay though.  I haven't yet gotten the chance to migrate something over to Sci-fi.SE.

Comment: ... or Worldbuilding for that matter.